# Reordering items in LazyVerticalGrid via long click drag

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose I have a [LazyVerticalGrid](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyVerticalGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.GridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Function1)) and I would like to add the long click drag to reorder the items, as we usually do with the `RecyclerView` and `GridLayoutManager` like in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iGte.gif)

This is my simple grid

```kotlin
LazyVerticalGrid(
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(2)
) {
    itemsIndexed(list) { _, item ->
        ...
    }
}
```

How could it be implemented?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question?

Comment: This has to be implemented by hand as there does not exist an API as of now. However, you could use this library until an API is published: https://github.com/aclassen/ComposeReorderable